# 5-cell "4D tetrahedron"

Tags: projective-space, visualization

I do not know if this is the right place to ask this.
But if I have a 3D object (tetrahedron) I can make a projection of it into 2D space where I use colour as the third dimension to determine height.

Now if I want to make a 4d projection into a 3D space I should be able to do something similar with the forth dimention - projecting it to colour and applying it to a 3D object. Is there something similar being done somewhere? Like has anybody made atool tomake these kind of visualizations?

Comment: The straightforward way would have one color extreme everywhere on the surface of the 3D tetrahedron, and the opposite extreme at the center of the 3D tetrahedron. Which I can "visualize" in a way in my head, but a 3D model wouldn't be interesting until you slice it open.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly doable mathematically. You would have to figure out how to "see" the inside of the three dimensional projection - perhaps by cutting it in half and showing only half. I know of no tools explicitly built for this task but it could probably be done with [openscad](https://openscad.org/).